# Select query to append columns with comma operator and ignoring nulls or empty values

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, select

We have a requirement of appending around three varchar columns of table with comma operator. Also we need to ignore the NULL or Empty Values during append. Suppose the table structure is as below

```
declare @t table (col1 varchar(10),col2 varchar(10),col3 varchar(10))
insert into @t
select 'test1','test2','test3' union all
select 'test4',null,'test5' union all
select null,null,'test6' union all
select '','test7',''
```

Expected result must be as below

```
Result
--------------------------------
test1,test2,test3
test4,test5
test6
test7
```

I have tried using case statements, but the query is becoming very complex. BTW we are using SQL Server 2005. Looking for any easy and simple solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not very elegant;

```
;with T(string) as (
    select
      isnull(case col1 when '' then null else col1 + ',' end, '')
    + isnull(case col2 when '' then null else col2 + ',' end, '')
    + isnull(case col3 when '' then null else col3 + ',' end, '')
    from @t
)
select left(string, abs(len(string) - 1)) from T
```

Comment: You could also try this:

SELECT 
COALESCE(NULLIF(col1, '') + ',', '') + 
COALESCE(NULLIF(col2, '') + ',', '') + 
COALESCE(NULLIF(col3, '') + ',', '')
from @t

Comment: @MLF Adds an extra , at the end of each row

Answer (score 2):

Here is a very alternative way

```
select reverse(stuff(reverse(coalesce(replace(col1, col1, col1 + ','), '')+ 
coalesce(replace(col2, col2, col2 + ','), '')+
coalesce(replace(col3, col3, col3 + ','), '')), 1,1,'')) Result from @t
```

Comment: You can wrap the whole statement in an isnull as if all 3 fields are '' or null, you'll get a null back

Comment: I hope this is bit more complex/tedious when the number of appending columns are more.

Comment: suryakiran I have no idea which sql performs better. I just assumed it would be faster than a subselect. Part of the reason I posted it was showing a way to remove the extra ',' without using a subselect

Answer (score 1):

Basically, just append a comma to each column if that column is not null / empty.Then, strip the last comma off of the result.

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN RIGHT(T.outColumn, 1) = ',' THEN SUBSTRING(T.outColumn, 1, LEN(T.outColumn) - 1)
        ELSE T.outColumn
    END
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        ISNULL(col1, '') + CASE WHEN ISNULL(col1, '') <> '' THEN ',' ELSE '' END +
        ISNULL(col2, '') + CASE WHEN ISNULL(col2, '') <> '' THEN ',' ELSE '' END +
        ISNULL(col3, '') AS outColumn
    FROM
        @t
    ) AS T
```